# Command line: create file with new filename if the filename already exists

Tags: command-line, files

I was wondering if it was possible have a command that creates one file, but every time the command is executed, it wouldn't overwrite the file created in the previous execution.

For example: `touch test1.txt` would create 1 file called `test1.txt`. But the next time I execute it, I would like the new file to be called `test2.txt`, or something like that. So without overwriting the already existing file. In a way it could be executed multiple times without problems.

Don't misunderstand me, I'm not trying to create multiple files with one command.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to add a timestamp to the filename and not use a single digit.

The easiest method to create an empty file would be `touch test$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)` and that would result in a file named `test20110802-170410`. A 2nd time `test*` will get a newer timestamp so it will result in 2 files.

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thanks! :)

Comment: Does not work in a script (not waiting between) - I tried `touch test$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S) ; touch test$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S)`, it created only one file. Nanoseconds-time works: `touch test$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%N) ; touch test$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%N)` and `touch test$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%N) test$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%N)` create two files each.

Comment: Is better to use `$()` since allows you to nest expressions, but you can also use backticks:  `touch test\`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S\``.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt a general command exist to do that, but you can think of something like this:

```
create() {
  read prefix number suffix < <(sed -r 's/(.*)([0-9]+)\.(.*)$/\1 \2 \3/' <<<"$1")
  while true; do
    file="$prefix$number.$suffix"
    if [[ -e "$file" ]]; then
      ((number++))
    else
      touch "$file"
      break
    fi
  done
}
```

The input parameter to the function is split in prefix, number, suffix, then until the file exists, the number is incremented. Found a free slot, the file is created with `touch`.

The split mechanism should be adapted to your needs, and various error check should be added.

Comment: brilliant, great function.

Answer (score 1):

If sequence numbers are not required, then the easiest way is to use `mktemp` command.

Comment: mktemp generates a random, unique filename, using a template. You'd likely capture the output of mktemp in a variable. From [linuxmanpages](http://linuxmanpages.com/man1/mktemp.1.php): `TMPFILE=$(mktemp /tmp/example.XXXXXXXXXX) || exit 1
echo "program output" >> $TMPFILE`

Comment: Another common method is to use the current process id, from the shell variable $$: `TMPFILE='/tmp/tmp.$$'; touch $TMPFILE`